# How to use selector function from different class in iOS Swift, mainly for NotificationCenter

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am using Tab Bar Controller in an iOS app and I am using reachability for checking the network availability and for achieving it I am using Notifications.

The basic syntax of a notification in Swift 3 is as follows -

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(observer: Any, selector: Selector, name: NSNotification.Name?, object: Any)
```

and things happen generally this way -

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(observer: self, selector: #selector(ViewControllerName.functionName), name: NameOfTheNotification, object: nil)
```

What I want to do is -

I want to use a static function present in different class for selector i.e.., when this notification is generated I want to call the static function which is present in the different class.

let's say the class name is "Functions" and the name of function is "myFunction()"

in simple words what I want to do is whenever the notification is there I want to call myFunction() function from class Functions.

**What I had tried**

I had tried doing this but it doesn't help -

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(observer: Functions(), selector: #selector(Functions.myFunction), name: NameOfTheNotification, object: nil)
```

There occurs an error and that error is as follows -
I had attached the Xcode snapshot below.
[image: shapshot of the error]

Comment: done that. It actually does nothing adds @objC at some where random place in the class and create more errors.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest fix is to add `@objc` to `reachabilityStatusChanged`.

```
// ↓
@objc func reachabilityStatusChanged(notification: Notification) { 
    ...
}
```

But NotificationCenter doesn't really require your class to support Objective-C. You could use [the block variant of the method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/notificationcenter/1411723-addobserver):

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name("ReachStatusChanged"), object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
    // do whatever Swift code with `notification` here.
    // no need to add @objc anywhere.
    reachabilityStatusChanged(notification)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but I triend doing this but it's not working I mean addObserver with completion handler is not executing anything I mean I tried putting some debug Print statements there but nothing happening.

Comment: @user3745635 Are you sure the notification name is spelled correctly?

Comment: yea I am sure. btw, I meanaged to get the functionality I wanted by making extension for UIViewController and adding that method there because I didn't find any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you're experimenting here is the interoperability with obj-C.

Make sure you expose the function `reachabilityStatusChanged' to obj-C with the @objc annotation.

`@objc func reachabilityStatusChanged`

Also, make sure the class `Functions` is visible to obj-c. (Inheriting it from NSObject)

Comment: Hi, THanks for responding but it's not working I mean the error is removed but the notification is not calling the function.

Comment: Mate, that's another problem. :) The problem that you're experimenting is that your not retaining `Functions()` then the systems will automatically unregister the observer, therefore it won't be called. (This feature was included by iOS recently). You should retain `Functions()` object in order to receive the notification.

Answer (score 0):

An illustration of why you have to retain `Functions()`

```
class Foo {
    @objc func test() {
        print("Hello")
    }
}

var foo: Foo? = Foo()
let nc = NotificationCenter.default

nc.addObserver(foo!,
               selector: #selector(Foo.test),
               name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Barrr"),
               object: nil)

nc.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Barrr"), object: nil)
nc.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Barrr"), object: nil)

foo = nil

nc.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Barrr"), object: nil)
```

This will print `Hello` twice instead of three times because foo class was deallocated before the third call.

Comment: Got it. Thanks would go through it.